# How are attributes allocated?

Tags: diablo-iii

Whenever a player levels up, they are granted points in 4 attributes: Dexterity, Strength, Intelligence, and Vitality.

Are these stat allocations based on anything the player does or are they set for each level dependent on class? What about attributes gained from Paragon levels?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Stat allocations are based on class, and are the same across all players.

Unlike Diablo II, there is no input required to assign stats on level-up. It's just free stats that happen the same for everyone!

As far as I'm aware, your character will always gain:

> +3 Primary Stat
>
> +2 Vitality
>
> +1 to both Secondary Stats.