# What are the base statistics for Diablo 3 classes?

Tags: diablo-iii

I am currently making a spreadsheet of all the classes (at level 60) stats when they are wearing no gear.  What are the base statistics (wearing no gear) for the monk, wizard, and witch doctor?

If you have any of those classes at lvl 60 could you please take off all your gear and post all your stats, I would be eternally grateful!!

EDIT:

I apologize, I should have clarified, I need all statistics, not just the dex,int,vit, and str. so armour, damage, resistances, dodge chance etc please

Answer (score 9):

Level 1 characters start with:

- 10 in primary stat
- 8 in secondary stats
- 9 vitality

*Source: my tests*

At each level, you get:

- +3 to primary stat
- +1 to secondary stats
- +2 vitality

*[Source](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66734/how-are-attributes-allocated)*

So, at level 60 (after 59 level-ups), all characters should have (assuming I did the math right):

- 187 in primary stat
- 67 in secondary stats
- 127 in vitality

Primary stat: strength for barbarians, dexterity for monks and demon hunters, and intelligence for wizards and witch doctors.

Derived stats:

- Armor: 1 armor per point of strength
- Dodge: 0.1% per point of dexterity at first, then changes by [a formula](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/68633/how-much-dodge-do-i-get-per-point-in-dexterity)
- Resistances: 0.1 per point of intelligence
- Damage: [+1% per point of primary stat](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/60281/how-is-skill-damage-calculated-based-on-weapon-damage)

(although I am not sure if there is any base armor or dodge added to these values)

Comment: yes this is true but everything else is different, like the armour, damage, dodge chance, etc.

Comment: @Chris Armor, dodge, damage, etc. is derived from the base stats.

Comment: @Chris I updated the post with some of the formulas for the derived stats.

Comment: Does this mean that all characters have the same amount of base HP regardless of class?

Comment: @Rachel I believe HP is independent of class, but am not 100% certain. I can't test it right now. Of course, monks and barbarians have an innate 30% damage reduction, but that's independent of health.