# How do attribute/stat increases scale after level 60 (Paragon levels)?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How are attributes allocated?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66734/how-are-attributes-allocated)

> Every Paragon level will reward you with: **Core stats such as Strength, Dexterity, Intelligence, and Vitality in amounts similar to what you’d gain from a normal level**; 3% Magic Find and 3% Gold Find<sup>[1](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/6968517/)</sup>

I can't find a decent explanation on how these core stats scale for each level.
Exactly how much does each stat change with every successive Paragon level?
Are the gains more significant after a certain point, or are gains linear with Paragon level?

Comment: well i think the boundaries of the question is around the same but i think it refers to paragon levels. though it seems that the stats allocation does turns out the same, the question in itself may not be a duplicate.

Comment: @jonleech - The existing question was updated to include information about Paragon attributes.  Also, yes, it is the same as normal levels

Comment: @OrigamiRobot - but yeah i think the question is answered either way but thanks for finding the thread.